# Let $A$ be real square matrix of order $n$ and if $A$ has complex eigenvalues then their corresponding eigenvectors must be complex.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A$ be a real square matrix of order $n$ and if $A$ has complex(non-zero imaginary part) eigenvalues then their corresponding eigenvectors must be complex.

I found one obvious example:

\begin{equation}A=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

which has two distinct eigenvalues that are $i $ and $-i $
and corresponding eigenvectors are also complex.

I believe that it is true for any matrix but am unable to prove it.

Am I correct? If yes then can someone help to prove it? And if it is not true then give one counterexample.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I take it that by "complex" you really mean "not real". Anyway, a real matrix times a real vector will be a real vector, so if that vector is an eigenvector then the corresponding eigenvalue will certainly be real.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for commenting, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that since all real numbers are also complex numbers, so *any* $n\times n$ matrix has exactly $n$ complex eigenvalues (counted with multiplicity).  So what you're asking literally is trivially true.

What I think you mean by 'complex' here is 'complex with nonzero imaginary part' or 'complex and not real'.

In that case, then

- if the entries/elements of $A$ are all real ($A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$), then the answer is yes: if all eigenvectors are complex, then all eigenvalues are complex.  We can prove this by contradiction: Let $x$ be an eigenvector with  non-real eigenvalue $\lambda$.  Assume $x$ is real.  Then since $Ax=\lambda x$, the rhs is a non-real vector, and the lhs is a real vector.  Thus we have a contradiction, so $x$ must be non-real.
- if we allow the entries of $A$ to be complex on ($A\in \mathbb C^{n\times n}$), in general, then the answer is no

Answer (score 2):

First of all, real numbers are also complex numbers, so I interpret your question as asking whether a real square matrix $A$ with nonreal eigenvalues $λ$ can have real eigenvectors $x$.

The answer is no. Let's recall the definition of eigenvalue $λ$:
$$Ax = λx$$

where $x$ is a nonzero vector. If $x$ is real and $A$ is real, then $λx$ must also be a real vector.
However, a nonreal number $λ$ multiplied by a nonzero real vector $x$ is never real.

Answer (score 2):

For any eigenvalue $\lambda\in\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb R$ and associated eigenvector $v\in\Bbb C^n\setminus\{0\},$ let us prove by contradiction that $v\notin\Bbb R^n.$

$Av=\lambda v$ and if $v\in\Bbb R^n$ then $Av\in\Bbb R^n,$ whereas $\lambda v\notin\Bbb R^n.$

Comment: Before answering, I spent some time searching a duplicate but to my surprise, couldn't find any.